# Hyper-V 2012 and VM web server http

Tags: hyper-v, http

I have a a few windows 2008 R2 Datacenter machines and a few windows 2012 Datacenter machines. I was runnin RedHat 6.2 VM on 2008 and all my other servers could access it over http until I put a VM up on 2012. No mater what I have done, (turned off selinux, firewall, iptables), on both RedHat servers has allowed them to pass http traffic. They can ping each other and ssh to each other but not http. I tried turning off the windows firewalls to, but no joy. I then moved the RedHat VM to the 2012 server and now the two RedHat VM's can http to each other, but none of the other vm's on other 2012 and 2008 servers can communicate over http.

Anyone have some insight?

Comment: Sounds like you've configured host-only networking.

Comment: Can you see the HTTP GETs coming in if you run TCPDump on the linux hosts?  Installing another guest shouldn't bother the guest systems.